# The use of 'de' between verbs

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, verbos, gerundio

I have a basic understanding of Spanish which I am trying to improve.

Can someone please explain, in brief, why the following type of sentence includes 'de' ?

'estoy tratando de estudiar' which in English simply translates to ' I am trying to study'

Thanks in advance for any replies

Andrew

Comment: If I wanted to translate _try_ then _tratar_ would not be the first word that sprang to mind. Can you edit to give a reference to where you saw the sentence you quote perhaps with some surrounding context?

Comment: Google translate. Not the best translation option I know.

Comment: I was just looking for an 'easy to understand' answer really as to why 'de' is being added/used before the infinitive or is being used after 'ing'

Answer (score 1):

Spanish grammar is very similar to English grammar in this regard. Some verbs typically collocate with prepositions and learners have to learn such uses.

Consider the following wrong sentences in English:

```
The price will depend the chosen materials. (X)
The customer insisted a discount. (X)
This machine consists two parts. (X)
```

These sentences are wrong because the verbs require certain prepositions:

```
The price will depend *on* the chosen materials.
The customer insisted *on* a discount.
This machine consists *of* two parts.
```

While native speakers simply get used to the fact that they say 'depend on', 'insist on' or 'consist of', learners of English must learn such verbs in combination with the right preposition.

It is the same in Spanish, but neither the list of verbs that require a preposition nor the prepositions involved are necessarily the same, so you need to learn which prepositions to use, if any. For example, 'depend on' is 'depender de' in Spanish (not, as you might expect, *'depender sobre').

For the verb 'try' you have two common options: one is the verb 'intentar', which is a plain transitive verb used without a preposition, but you also have the verb + preposition combination 'tratar de'. So, for 'I am trying to study' you have two valid translations:

```
Estoy intentando estudiar.
Estoy tratando de estudiar.
```

Comment: That's right. The short and long of it, you have to memorize it. Just like in English, for those learning it. Your answer is right on point for a learner.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que mejor que puedes hacer es estudiar poco a poco los distintos usos de "**de**" y complementar con algunos ejercicios que te ayuden a entender su uso.

13. "**de**" - **preposición Usada precedida de un verbo para formar perífrasis verbales.** **Dejó de estudiar**. **Acaba de llegar**. "Estoy **tratando de** estudiar".

---

**De**

Del lat. de.

1. prep. Denota posesión o pertenencia. La casa de mi padre. La paciencia de Job.
2. prep. U. para crear diversas locuciones adverbiales de modo. Almorzó de pie. Le dieron de puñaladas. Se viste de prestado. Lo conozco de vista.
3. prep. Denota de dónde es, viene o sale alguien o algo. La piedra es de Colmenar. Vengo de Aranjuez. No sale de casa.
4. prep. Denota la materia de que está hecho algo. El vaso de plata. El vestido de seda.
5. prep. U. para señalar lo contenido en algo. Un vaso de agua. Un plato de asado.
6. prep. Denota asunto o materia. Este libro trata de la última guerra. Una clase de matemáticas. Hablaban de la boda.
7. prep. Denota la causa u origen de algo. Murió de viruelas. Fiebre del heno.
8. prep. U. para expresar la naturaleza, condición o cualidad de alguien o algo. Hombre de valor. Entrañas de fiera.
9. prep. U. para determinar o fijar con mayor viveza la aplicación de un nombre apelativo. El mes de noviembre. La ciudad de Sevilla.
10. prep. desde (‖ denota el punto del que procede algo). De Madrid a Toledo. Abierto de nueve a una.
11. prep. U. precedida de sustantivo, adjetivo o adverbio, y seguida de infinitivo. Es hora de caminar. Harto de trabajar. Lejos de pensar.
12. prep. U. seguida de infinitivo con valor condicional. De saberlo antes, habría venido.

**13.** prep. U. precedida de un verbo para formar perífrasis verbales. Dejó de estudiar. Acaba de llegar.

14. prep. U. con ciertos nombres para determinar el tiempo en que sucede algo. De madrugada. De mañana. De noche. De viejo. De niño.
15. prep. U. para reforzar un calificativo. El bueno de Pedro. El pícaro del mozo. La taimada de la patrona.
16. prep. U. como nota de ilación. De esto se sigue. De aquello se infiere.
17. prep. U. con valor partitivo. Dame un poco de agua.
18. prep. Denota la rápida ejecución de algo. De UN trago se bebió la tisana. De UN salto se puso en la calle. Acabemos de UNA vez.
19. prep. U. entre distintas partes de la oración con expresiones de lástima, queja o amenaza. ¡Pobre de mi hermano! ¡Ay de los vencidos!
20. prep. U. para la creación de locuciones prepositivas a partir de adverbios, nombres, etc. Antes de. Respecto de. Alrededor de. A diferencia de.
21. prep. U. también combinada con otras preposiciones. De a tres. De a bordo. De por sí. Por de pronto. Tras de sí.
22. prep. U. en ciertas construcciones con el agente de la pasiva. Acompañado de sus amigos. Dejado de la mano de Dios. Está abrumado de deudas.
23. prep. U. para introducir el término de la comparación. He comido más de lo debido. Es peor de lo que pensaba. Ahora escribe más de veinte artículos al año.
24. prep. con (‖ denota el medio que sirve para hacer algo). Lo hizo de intento.
25. prep. para. Gorro de dormir. Ropa de deporte.
26. prep. por. Lo hice de miedo.
27. prep. desuso a.

https://dle.rae.es/de

Answer (score 0):

In Spanish "perífrasis verbales de infinitivo" (verb phrases involving more than one lexical verb where the main verb is followed by an infinitive), we can find the following (where in English we only find an infinitive or a gerund after the main verb)

(1) verbs that are followed by an infinitive that is merely juxtaposed:

- Quiero estudiar (I want to study)
- Necesito estudiar (I need to study)
- Decido estudiar (I decide to study)
- Prefiero estudiar (I prefer to study)
- (Me) Propongo estudiar (I propose to study)
- Elijo estudiar (I choose to study)

(2) verbs that are followed by a preposition (typically "a" or "de") and an infinitive:

- Comienzo/Empiezo **a** estudiar (I start/begin to study)
- Voy **a** estudiar (I'm going to study)
- Termino **de** estudiar (I finish studying)
- Dejo **de** estudiar (I stop/give up studying)
- He **de** estudiar (formal: I am to study)
- Trato **de** estudiar (I try to study)

We can also find "que" between both verbs as in:

- Tengo que estudiar (I have to study)